# Change infoBox color based on a custom CSS in ShinyDashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Below is are two separate InfoBox codes present in  server function of ShinyDashboard

```
infoBox("Responses submitted",ParterCount$count, icon=icon("pencil-square-o"), color = "red", fill = F)

infoBox("Contact Person", unique(Contact), icon=icon("user"), color = "red",fill = F)
```

Below is the image output on ShinyDashboard [image: Image output on ShinyDashboard]

I'd like to change the color from red to a custom color that I can load from CSS.

How do I go about that?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
            div(
                class ="my-info-group",
                infoBox("Responses submitted",1, icon=icon("fas fa-edit"), color = "red", fill = F),
                infoBox("Contact Person", "Jane Doe", icon=icon("user"), color = "red",fill = F)
            ),
            tags$style(
                '
                .my-info-group .info-box-icon {background-color: blue !important;}
                '
            )
        ),
        title = "Dashboard example"
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Put your boxes under an element with `my-info-group` class, then you can style your box colors as above.

[image]